# Comparison between "parfor" in Matlab and "Prange" in Python. Something worng with "parfor"

Tags: python, matlab, parallel-processing

"parfor" in Matlab and "Prange" in Python are both simple parrllel computation function. We can test them in the following code (matlab only, since I encounter some problem in Matlab)

```
len = 1e10;
sum1 = 0;
sum2 = 0;

fprintf("use for: ");
tic
for i = 1:len
    sum1 = sum1 + 0.1;
end
toc

fprintf("use parfor: ");
tic
parfor i = 1:len
    sum2 = sum2 + 0.1;
end
toc
```

We will see clearly, the "parfor" is much faster than the "for" (remember to set parpool function before using). And it is the same for the "Prange" in Python. In addition, it is the same for some more complex computation, such as multiplication and so on (remember not to test those computation that have been internally parallelized for optimization, such as matrix multiplication).

But, when we come to some operations related to RAM reading, such as read a matrix element. "Prange" works well, while "parfor" perform badly. Let's see the following codes

```
len = 2e8;
A = rand(len, 1);
sum1 = 0;
sum2 = 0;

fprintf("use for: ");
tic
for i = 1:len
    sum1 = sum1 + A(i);
end
toc

fprintf("use parfor: ");
tic
parfor i = 1:len
    sum2 = sum2 + A(i);
end
toc
```

Using "parfor" is much slower than using "for". In the same situation, "Prange" works well and is faster than "range".

I have run the Matlab and Python codes. Python works well, while Matlab works badly when coming to reading RAM.

I want to know whether "parfor" performs badly when reading from RAM or some operation like this. And I want to know why "Prange" works well.

Comment: You probably already know this, but `sum(A)` is parallelized and impossible to beat.

Comment: You don’t show how you configure your parallel pool. By default it uses a process-based parallelism, which requires copying the input array to all worker processes. You can also configure it to use threads instead. See the documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/choose-between-thread-based-and-process-based-environments.html

Comment: Also this is a terrible example of a parallel loop, as all the iteration depends on the previous iteration, thus not trivially paralelizable. This is generally computed with a reduction, and certainly is a very particular case of a non-trivially parallelizable code, that has to be studied by its own lens, rather than a general look.

Comment: As for the parallel pool configuration, I just simply set `parpool("local",4);`

The two examples above, are both the case as Ander Biguri says "the iteration depends on the previous iteration". I don't know why in the first example, "parfor" is much faster than "for", while in the second example "parfor" is much slower than "for".

Comment: @AnderBiguri That's not strictly correct that each iteration depends on the previous iteration. `parfor` supports parallel reduction such as this case by assuming associativity of the operation. (It's still a terrible loop for a process pool, `parpool("Threads")` should fare better)

Comment: @Edric ah yes, of course. I just wanted to point out that this particular example is a somehow unique problem in parallelization, as the nature of the performance for this problem is very different than other more trivially paralelizable problems. I did more or less suspect this is done with reduction, because of the performance, of course.