# high data transfer cost in Matlab parallel computing

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

In [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75865680/7328782), we discussed the use of `parpool('Processes')`. In such a parpool setting, if we perform a cheap operation, `parfor` can become badly slow due to the costs of transferring data between processes. This can be demonstrated using the `ticBytes(gcp)` function.

Based on the suggestions of @Cris Luengo and @Edric, I switched to using `parpool('Threads')`. It is expected that for large-scale cases, `parfor` should be faster than `for`. I have tested this using various scales ranging from 1e3 to 1e9, and the code is shown below.

```
len = 8e8;
A = rand(len, 1);
sum1 = 0;
sum2 = 0;

fprintf("Using for loop: ");
tic
for i = 1:len
    sum1 = A(i);
end
toc

fprintf("Using parfor loop: ");
tic
parfor i = 1:len
    sum2 = A(i);
end
toc
```

I have made some interesting observations and formulated the following statements:

1. When the scale is small, for example 1e3, `parfor` is slower than `for`, because some inner parallel scheduling is executed. This cost is larger than the cost of the "plus" operation.
2. When the scale is very large, for example 1e9, `parfor` is still much slower than `for`, because the RAM of my computer (16GB) is not sufficient for storing such a huge matrix and reading it from RAM. This can be demostrated by the Windows task manager.
3. When the scale is appropriate, for example 6e8 or 7e8, `parfor` is faster than `for`. I hope this is not a statistical error.

The results are out, I have average my computations under every scale for 10 times. It seems that, `parfor` is always slower than `for`. The figure below is the times costs comparison. The x-label is scale of matrix, and the y-label is time costs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It’s not the computation that takes time, it is the data transfer. How simple the computation is is irrelevant. You’re using a process-based parallel model, as explained in the linked answer. This means inter-process communication, which takes non-trivial time. Using a thread-based parallel model you should see faster results. But it’ll always be slower than `sum(A)`.

Comment: Also, in your [previous question about the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75865680/7328782) both I and Edric recommended you use thread-based parallelism, but I guess you haven’t done that. I’m not sure where you’re going with this, but if after the experiment you did in your previous post you still don’t see that data transfer is expensive and that you should avoid that if possible, then I don’t know how to help you. Have you read the answer I linked as duplicate? Have you read the documentation pages linked in that answer? The docs are really clear about how things work.

Comment: @Cris Luengo. Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried using 'parpool("Threads")' instead of 'parpool("Processes")' as suggested and it has significantly improved performance. However, even after making this change, my parfor loop is still twice as slow as the for loop (with the former one being tenth slower). Is it possible that there is an issue with caching reads that is causing this discrepancy?

Comment: Parallel execution has overhead. If what you do inside the loop is very cheap, it's not worth starting up threads. If you do a more expensive operation inside the loop, the parallel version will be faster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I have some other finds.
1. We can consider a more cheap operation, 'sum1 = sum1 + 0.001' for example. 'parfor' is more faster than 'for' in both "threads" and "process" parallel.
2. In python, using 'Prange()' to do whatever a cheap operation, is always faster than 'range()'. This is different from matlab.

Comment: With `sum1 = sum1 + 0.001`, a parallel version is *maybe* faster if you iterate many, many times. But I’d have a hard time believing that l, if `sum2 = sum2 + A(i)` is not faster. I would suggest you update your question with the exact code you used to time this, I think the timing code might be wrong.

Comment: `prange` is Numba, which means it is not Python executing the code. There also, a parallelized loop is only faster than the sequential one if the total loop time is large enough to compensate for the parallelization overhead. Adding 100 numbers is not enough work, adding a billion numbers probably is.

Comment: @Cris Luengo, thank you for your consistent attention. Based on your suggestions, I have rewritten my question. I would like to express my gratitude for the helpful discussion with you and Edric. It enables me to handle almost all practical situations.